# Docker deployment on EB Beanstalk fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The docker containers that I deploy onto a beanstalk instance don't seem to start successfully. There isn't much info showing WHY it failed...

Here is my Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "essential": true,
            "name": "api",
            "image": "<user>/<repo>:latest",
            "memory": 256,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "hostPort": 8000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "postgres:latest",
            "memory": 256,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data/",
                    "sourceVolume": "Postgres_Data"
                }
            ],
            "name": "db"
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "nginx:latest",
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
                    "sourceVolume": "_Nginx"
                }
            ],
            "name": "nginx",
            "memory": 256,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 443,
                    "hostPort": 443
                },
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "postgres_data"
            },
            "name": "Postgres_Data"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "nginx"
            },
            "name": "_Nginx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Part of the error log (`eb logs`). There aren't even any level=warn or level=error parts in the logs, which makes this more confusing.

```
[2020-08-16T08:51:08.224Z] INFO  [4078]  - [Application deployment app-200816_014520@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02update-credentials.sh] : Starting activity...
[2020-08-16T08:51:08.426Z] INFO  [4078]  - [Application deployment app-200816_014520@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/02update-credentials.sh] : Completed activity.
[2020-08-16T08:51:08.426Z] INFO  [4078]  - [Application deployment app-200816_014520@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03start-task.sh] : Starting activity...
[2020-08-16T08:52:11.081Z] INFO  [4078]  - [Application deployment app-200816_014520@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/03start-task.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/common.sh
  + RETRY=0
  + initctl start eb-ecs EB_EVENT_FILE=/tmp/eventsfile20200816-4078-1yuoqug
  initctl: Job failed to start
  + '[' -f /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.eb-ecs-start-no-retry ']'
  + warn 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
  + echo 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
  Failed to start ECS task, retrying...
  + eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...' --severity WARN
  + RETRY=1
  + sleep 3
  + '[' 1 -gt 1 ']'
  + initctl start eb-ecs EB_EVENT_FILE=/tmp/eventsfile20200816-4078-1yuoqug
  initctl: Job failed to start
  + '[' -f /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.eb-ecs-start-no-retry ']'
  + warn 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
  + echo 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
  Failed to start ECS task, retrying...
  + eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...' --severity WARN
  + RETRY=2
  + sleep 3
  + '[' 2 -gt 1 ']'
  + error_exit 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.' 1
  + error 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.'
  + echo 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.'
  Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.
  + eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.' --severity ERROR
  + exit 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/common.sh
  + RETRY=0
  + initctl start eb-ecs EB_EVENT_FILE=/tmp/eventsfile20200816-4078-1yuoqug
  initctl: Job failed to start
  + '[' -f /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.eb-ecs-start-no-retry ']'
  + warn 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
  + echo 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
  Failed to start ECS task, retrying...
  + eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...' --severity WARN
  + RETRY=1
  + sleep 3
  + '[' 1 -gt 1 ']'
  + initctl start eb-ecs EB_EVENT_FILE=/tmp/eventsfile20200816-4078-1yuoqug
  initctl: Job failed to start
  + '[' -f /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.eb-ecs-start-no-retry ']'
  + warn 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
  + echo 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...'
  Failed to start ECS task, retrying...
  + eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task, retrying...' --severity WARN
  + RETRY=2
  + sleep 3
  + '[' 2 -gt 1 ']'
  + error_exit 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.' 1
  + error 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.'
  + echo 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.'
  Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.
  + eventHelper.py --msg 'Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.' --severity ERROR
  + exit 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

How to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe could try running a basic example of docker container, e.g. [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxdemos/hello/). Once this is working, then can build on top of this exercise and how to run your custom image?